# Convert String to Int in a Single Line C#

Tags: c#, string, sum, integer

I have a string input like:

`1 3 4 1 2`

I want to `Sum` the number into integer. I tried the following code:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input2 = "1 3 4 1 1";
        string value2 = input2.Replace(" ", "+");
        int val = int.Parse(value2);
        
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}
```

But it is not correct. Does anyone have an idea for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Split on space. Convert to a list of int.

Comment: `int val = input2.Split(" ").Sum(int.Parse);`

Comment: "1+3+4+1+2" is not a valid integer, so int.Parse is correctly refusing to convert that into an int.  You can Split the string on spaces, then `.Select(str => int.Parse(str))` then `.Sum` the result.  (Or just `.Sum(int.Parse)` all at once)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Split `input2` with a space character into an `array` then use [system.linq.enumerable.sum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0)

```
   string input2 = "1 3 4 1 1";
   var result=  input2.Split(' ').Sum(x=> int.Parse(x));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, you are right

Comment: `int result = "1 3 4 1 1".Split().Sum(int.Parse);`

Answer (score 7):

You can try `Split` the initial string (`input2`) into items, `TryParse` them into corresponding `int` bvalues and then `Sum` them with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int val = value2 
  .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Sum(item => int.TryParse(item, out int value) ? value : 0);
```

Here all *invalid* items (i.e. items which *can't be parsed* as an integer) are *ignored* (we turn them into `0`). You may want an exception thrown in this case:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int val = value2 
  .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Sum(item => int.Parse(item));
```

Finally, your code amended (we can use an old trick with `DataTable.Compute`):

```
using System.Data;

...

string input2 = "1 3 4 1 1";

string formula = input2.Replace(' ', '+');

using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
{
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute(formula, null));

    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Comment: Better to throw an exception than to treat garbage as 0, in my opinion.

Comment: TryParse doesn't seem appropriate here. There's no indication that the input can have anything besides digits and spaces.

Comment: I think parsing to 0 is perfectly valid for this specific use case, as adding 0 literally does nothing to the sum. In the case of other statistics like an average? that's a completely different story

Comment: @Narish: in general case (`Average` and other statistics) we can *filter out* invalid valies: instead of `.Sum(...)` we can put `.Select(item => item.TryParse(item, out int value) ? (value, parsed : true) : (0, false)).Where(item => item.parsed).Select(item => item.value).MyStatistics(item => item);`

Comment: That's a super interesting bit of LINQ, are you using tuples here?

Comment: @Narish: yes, I've used named tuple `(int value, bool parsed)` here: mechanical combination of integer and boolean values.